# Laravel 5 Validate many to many data

Tags: validation, many-to-many, laravel-5

When creating a new `Role` an administrator can select different rights he'd like to assign to that role. After saving the freshly created `Role` to the database, the selected rights are sync'd to the `right_role` table.

```
public function store(CreateRoleRequest $request) {
    $role = new Role(['name' => $request->get('name')]);

    $rights = [];
    foreach ($request->get('rights') as $id => $enabled) {
        if ($enabled) {
            $rights[] = $id;
        }
    }

    $role->save();
    $role->rights()->sync($rights);

    return redirect()->route('users.index');
}
```

But how do I validate the submitted rights against not existing values? Can I do this within my `CreateRoleRequest`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with custom validator. Here is example how the custom validators can be used in CreateRoleRequest

```
public function __construct() {
    Validator::extend("valid_rights", function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
        $rules = [
            'right_id' => 'exists:rights,id'
        ];
        foreach ($value as $rightId) {
                $data = [
                    'right_id' => $rightId
                ];
                $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);
                if ($validator->fails()) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        return true;
    });
}

public function rules() {
    return [
        'containers' => 'required|valid_rights',
    ];
}
```